# When did Mulder and Scully meet Sveta?

Tags: the-x-files, x-files-tv-miniseries

In *My Struggle* (S10E01), Mulder and Scully are introduced to Sveta, who claims that they (or possibly just Mulder) interviewed her as a child. Neither Mulder or Scully seem to recall her, even despite her relating stories of her abductions.

**When, if at all, did Mulder and Scully meet Sveta before?**

Comment: As far as I know, that is one of the main mysteries/questions that will be answered throughout the new series. I haven't seen any of it yet, and I don't know how much you've seen either—but just in case you're just asking because it struck you as a curious minor thing, it's not (as far as I can tell). But unless episodes have already aired that tell us more, I don't think we can answer it yet.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wasn't sure if she was a minor character that was just so young at the time that it's not clicking, or if it was a lie, or if there was something else going on.

Comment: If what I've read about the new series (not much, but a bit) is true, then she is an absolutely pivotal character—the whole reason Mulder and Scully are back at all, and the key to basically uncertainising and discombobulating everything from the first nine seasons.

Comment: She's integral to them coming back together, that's true. Beyond that is very much up in the air as of the end of episode 1.

Comment: @phantom42 : Now that the miniseries has concluded, I've updated the answer below, as promised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Unknown...but the truth may be out there.

There is no character by the name of **"Sveta"** in any previous *X-Files* episode, as can be determined by searching through a script database, such as the excellent one maintained at http://www.insidethex.co.uk/.  It's possible that she appeared but her name was not mentioned, but I cannot reconcile her with any of the abductees we have seen in the previous 9 seasons.

From what we heard in **"My Struggle"** (the first episode of the new mini-series), Mulder and Scully themselves do not remember meeting Sveta, but they do not seem disturbed by their inability to remember her.  This can probably be squared up with the likelihood that they interviewed hundreds of abductees while the X-Files were active.

So the possibilities are that:

- Sveta's back story with regards to meeting Mulder and Scully will not be revealed (and that we are to assume that she was just one of hundreds of interviewed abductees); or
- her initial encounter with the agents is significant and will be discussed at some point in the new series; or
- they did not actually meet her prior to "My Struggle" and the story was fabricated for some reason.

*If and when we learn more, I will update this answer.  Given that the final episode of the mini-series will be titled "My Struggle II", there could be new details on the horizon.*

**UPDATE:** There is only a passing reference to Sveta in **"My Struggle II"** that sheds no further light on her past encounters with Mulder and Scully.  As a result, the answer above is unchanged.

Comment: Great answer as always, any insight into a [similar question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46737/7536) about the Old Man?

Comment: @Dpeif : Thanks.  He is definitely new to the story as well.  In particular, Mulder says he met the man 10 years ago, which would have been in 2006, between the final episode and *I Want to Believe*, and so this is a meeting we would have never seen.

Comment: "but the truth may be out there"

Comment: @Dpeif - the old man is the young doctor at Roswell; they added a mole to the young doctor guy to establish that; but there's no mention of the Old Man in previous episodes.

Comment: @Mikey : Definitely.  When the Old Man was speaking to Mulder they flashed back very briefly to him as the young doctor at Roswell.  Gut given that Mulder met him in 2006 ("10 years" before the time of the mini-series), we would never have seen this encounter on screen, as the original show ended in 2002 and *I Want to Believe* is set in 2008.